# Zotero server installation

Tags: server, zotero

I installed Ubuntu server on my conputer. I want to study zotero server code. I have to install Zotero open source server code on Ubuntu server. What command should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Official installation instructions for the Zotero data server are (deliberately ?) close to non-existent.

[Samuel Hassine](https://github.com/SamuelHassine) successfully managed to set up the Zotero server after seemingly much efforts and a number of patches.

His code and installation instructions are available [on GitHub](https://github.com/SamuelHassine/zotero-prime).